# Conceptual inquiry about __main__ in Python

Tags: python, function, program-entry-point, conceptual

I am currently working with Python and have been confused over the fact that functions are  listed in `__main__`. I have been looking over multiple python scripts to try to find a common theme as to what functions warrant a place in `__main__`, but to no avail. Here I have a sample of my own code. `firstfunction` and 
`anotherfunction` are the only two functions in my code.

```
def main(argv):

    firstinput=""
    secondinput=""

    if len(argv) < 3 or len(argv) > 3:
        print """"Please set to:
                metisfinal.main(metisfinal.py, firstinput, secondinput)""""
        return
    else:
        firstinput = argv[1]
        secondinput = argv[2]

    firstfunction(firstinput, dictionary)
    anotherfunction(list, secondinput)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

(I think) I know that the arguments and `__main__` call are correct, but  `firstfunction` and `anotherfunction` always return errors (because their arguments are not globally defined). I'm positive that this is arising from a faulty understanding of `__main__`, because all the other examples I've looked at, basically set up `__main__` in the same manner.

What constitutes listing a specific function in `__main__`? I have stumbled over some Python code that has upwards of 30 functions within it, but the programmer only listed 2 of those functions in `__main__`. Likewise, sometimes a code will have classes in the main argument, like this one (`Project` is earlier defined as an object class):

```
def main(argv):

    filename = ""
    outputfilename = ""

    p = Project(filename, outputfilename, subdomainNames) 
    p.generateICs()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Conceptually, I can't understand why all the functions aren't listed... don't all of them need to be run or is `__main__` simply initializing something?

Am I looking at atypical code? What key concepts of `__main__` am I missing? And once I do find what functions to put into `__main__`, is there a specific way to format them?

Comment: What do you mean by "put functions in `__main__`"?

Comment: @FogleBird I think like in C or C++ void main and etc )

Comment: @FogleBird for all the scripts I've looked at, there have been multiple functions from within the script listed again at the end in `__main__` I don't understand why. I thought `__main__` was simply a way to run the entire script with one call.

Comment: +1 for trying to verify and deepen your understanding. You'll be wrong at times, but that's how you learn.

Comment: @AllysonKim No its a not necessarily, you could write functions which you want call without indents and and any "main"

Comment: You can define functions inside the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block if they're only needed/useful when running the script directly. (Helpers for `main()` for example)

Comment: Thanks so much you guys, I really appreciate the help.. I understand its a basic question. Definitely makes more sense now. Man, Python can be different from MATLAB sometimes :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "listed in `__main__`".  `__main__` is not an entity in the source file.  Rather, it is the *name* of the module, if you execute it directly.  When you do `if __name__=="__main__"`, you are telling Python to execute the code in that block if and only if the code is being executed as the main module --- that is, if it is a program being run.  The code in the `if __name__=="__main__"` block will not be run if the module is imported from another module.

Note that you do not "list" functions in that if block.  Instead, you put *regular program code* in that block that you want to be run.  Often this code just calls one function.  Often people call that function `main()`.  But there is no special relationship between `__main__` and `main`.  You can call the function anything you like:

```
def snicklefritz():
    # This function will be run when you run the program
    print "You ran the program!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    snicklefritz()
```

Try running this program (say, by saving it as "snicklefritz.py" and then doing `python snicklefritz.py` from the command line).  You'll see "You ran the program!" printed.  If instead you create a separate file that does `import snicklefritz`, the message won't be printed.

Note that there's nothing about "listing functions".  For example, look at this program:

```
print "This will always be printed!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "This will only be printed if you run the file as a program!"
```

Here the `if __name__=="__main__"` block does not "list" any functions.  It just contains actual code that is run when the file is run as a script.  People usually don't do this, though, because it's more tidy to have the code in a separate function instead of just sitting there "exposed" outside of a function.

As for other functions, you can define whatever other functions you like in your module, to be used either within that module, or to be used by other modules that import your module.  Typically most of the functions in a module won't be used inside the `if __name__=="__main__"` block, because they won't be part of the "main" function.  Instead, they'll be other functions intended for use by other code.  For example:

```
def otherFunc(x):
    # Return x squared
    return x**2

def snicklefritz():
    # This function will be run when you run the program
    print "You ran the program!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    snicklefritz()
```

`otherFunc` is not used at all in the module.  That's fine.  It may be that someone will want to import your module and use `otherFunc` themselves.  Not every function has to be used within the same module, let alone be called from the `if __name__=="__main__"` block.

Comment: `__main__` is actually a module; you can even import it.

Comment: @Ignacio Woha indeed, it seems pretty empty though from a quick `dir(__main__)` - what is it good for?

Comment: That's true, but it's not an entity in the source file, like a function or class.  The OP seemed to think that `__main__` was a "place" within the source code.  Anyway, importing `__main__` as a module is a fairly obscure technique that's not that common in basic Python usage.  (It's used by threading libraries and the like, for instance.)

Comment: ok, that makes more sense. So, it simply tells the script what functions to run. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @Voo: It's for when scripts need to get self-referential.

Comment: I edited my reply to clarify: it doesn't list functions to run.  It contains actual code that is run.  You can put whatever you like in that block, not just calls to functions.

Answer (score 3):

You are misunderstanding the `__main__` idiom.

Consider the program below, saved in a file called `sum.py`:

```
def read_numbers():
    n1 = int(raw_input())
    n2 = int(raw_input())
    return n1, n2

def sum_numbers(i1, i2):
    return i1+i2

def print_sum(i1, i2, i3):
    print "%d + %d = %d" % (i1, i2, i3)

v1, v2 = read_numbers()
sum = sum_numbers(v1, v2)
print_sum(v1, v2, sum)
```

It has three functions - one reads two numbers from standard input, another sums them and the third one prints the operation. After defining the functions, I call them in such a way that we read two numbers and print its sum. Fairly easy. If I execute it, I get something like this:

```
$ python sum.py 
12
34
12 + 34 = 46
```

Now, suppose I need to write another program which will read only one number - the other number is actually given. Since I already have a `sum_numbers()` function and a `print_sum()` function, I can fell tempted to reuse the `sum` module, which is a good thing:

```
import sum
MY_FIXED_NUMBER=3
n = int(raw_input())
value = sum.sum_numbers(n, MY_FIXED_NUMBER)
print_sum(n, MY_FIXED_NUMBER, value)
```

Great! However, if I execute it, what I got? This:

```
$ python three_sum.py 
12
34
12 + 34 = 46
12
12 + 3 = 15
```

WAT?! The program asked me for two numbers, printed the sum of them and then asked for a third number, which is correctly summed to 3. I just wanted to be asked for the third number, and just to print the sum with 3! What happened?

It happened that, when I import a module (such as `import sum`), all code inside it is executed. So, my module has two parts, one which defines useful functions which can be used elsewhere (which I will call the *definition part*), and a part where it executes this function in a way to get a specific result, so I can use the module as a program (which I will call the *execution part*). The execution part is always executed.

Fortunately, Python has a trick to allow me to execute the execution part only when the module is *not* imported. If I import a Python file with `import`, the module will have a variable called `__name__`, whose name will be the original name of the module:

```
>>> import sum
12
34
12 + 34 = 46
>>> sum.__name__
'sum'
```

However, if I run the Python file as a script (`$ python sum.py`), the `__name__` variable will be there, but with a different name. Suppose I add a line such as

```
print __name__
```

at the end of my `sum.py`. When I run it again, I got it:

```
$ python sum.py
12
34
12 + 34 = 46
__main__
```

On the other hand, if I run `three_sum.py`, the result of `print __name__` is way different:

```
$ python three_sum.py 
12
34
12 + 34 = 46
sum
12
12 + 3 = 15
```

Yes, the value of the `__name__` variable when running the file as a script is `__main__`.

So, how could this help me? This way: I will put the execution part of my module inside a `if` condition. If the name of the module is `__main__`, it is because the file is running as a script with `$  python sum.py` - in this case, I should execute the execution part of my module. So my `sum.py` module will be this way now:

```
def read_numbers():
    n1 = int(raw_input())
    n2 = int(raw_input())
    return n1, n2

def sum_numbers(i1, i2):
    return i1+i2

def print_sum(i1, i2, i3):
    print "%d + %d = %d" % (i1, i2, i3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    v1, v2 = read_numbers()
    sum = sum_numbers(v1, v2)
    print_sum(v1, v2, sum)
```

If I run `$ python sum.py`, I get the same as before:

```
$ python sum.py
12
34
12 + 34 = 46
```

However, if I run `three_sum.py`, everything is different:

```
$ python three_sum.py 
12
12 + 3 = 15
```

Now this works as expected. It works this way because the name of the module in the first execution is `__main__`, so the commands under `if __name__ == "__main__"`  are executed. In the second execution, however, the name of the module is `sum`, so the commands under the `if` are not executed.

Even if your file is *not* designed to be imported, it is still a good practice to put the execution part of your file under `if __name__ == "__main__"`, so you file is easily adapted to become a module.

Comment: Oh, @BrenBarn arrived before me with an excellent answer :) I will leave mine because it has a slightly different approach, however.

Comment: +1 for such a detailed explanation! Thank you. It was very helpful to have a step by step process through everything (along with code examples). I will be revisiting this many a time.